# Warning C26451: Arithmetic overflow (when subtracting two ints)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When performing the following line of code:

```
int max = 50, min = -30;
double num = rand() % (max - min) - min;
```

I get the following warning from Visual Studio 2019:

Warning C26451 Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '-' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '-' to avoid overflow (io.2).

I'm not sure how this is applicable, as I am taking the modulus of a double, which will return and integer, and then subtracting another integer from it, before storing it in a double (which I'm fairly certain isn't the problem).

Is this a bug or am I doing something that could result in truncation etc.?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your expression be `rand() % (max - min) + min`, if you wanted to generate a number between `[min;max)`?

Comment: First, this is a **warning**, not an **error**. The code is valid and its meaning is well defined. A compiler that refuses to compile this code does not conform to the language definition. Apparently the compiler writer thought that code like this might be error prone, and you've amplified that opinion by using a setting that turns warnings into errors.

Comment: @geza oh wow yes haha, it should indeed be plus! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference (in both of subtractions) can result in overflow. The overflow may happen if you subtract negative values from positive, or positive values from negative.

For example, if you subtract something negative from a maximum possible value, you'll get an overflow.

As you have wider destination type, it is possible that you intend this wider result to fit this wider type without overflow. This will not happen, unless you cast one of your operands.

I don't think it is practical to do such cast here, as you use `%` operator, this will not work with `double`. And anyway it will not handle overflow, just because you cannot have more range here than range of `rand()`.

Apparently if you want to fix the possible overflow of `rand()`, you'll need `std::uniform_int_distribution` with your range. This would fix other `rand()` problems along (thread safety and not good randomness), but would add a bit of complexity as well.

But sure if you always have -30 to 50 range, there's no overflow, and you can treat it as a false warning. If you literally have `int max = 50, min = -30;` I even see it as a bug of static analysis to emit this warning. Sure static analysis cannot predict the result of `rand()`, but there's `%` to truncate it.  Maybe use *Help > Send Feedback > Report a problem* if you care.

Comment: Thanks very much - I understand now and will see if my program needs to catch those extreme cases.