# Warning C26451 Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '-'

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I don't understand why this issue is being flagged:

```
InitAssignmentCell(iNumRows - 1, strDescription, IMG_UNCHECKED, static_cast<LPARAM>(iNumRows - 1));
```

The definition for that method is:

```
InitAssignmentCell(int iRow, CString strAssignment, int iCheckState, LPARAM lParam)
```

So the final parameter is a `LPARAM`. Yet I am seeing some squiggles:

[image]

> Warning   C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '-' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '-' to avoid overflow (io.2).

I don't understand this because `iNumRows` is of type `int`.

I have seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443963/warning-c26451-arithmetic-overflow-when-subtracting-two-ints) which is along similar lines and my gut is that this is a false warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C26451 warning from the MSVC static analyser is *very* pedantic. It warns against the possibility that you may be assuming that promotion is automatically performed *before* the cast (which it is not).

To silence the warning, do the cast before the arithmetic. So, instead of:

```cpp
InitAssignmentCell(iNumRows - 1, strDescription, IMG_UNCHECKED, static_cast<LPARAM>(iNumRows - 1));
```

Use:

```cpp
InitAssignmentCell(iNumRows - 1, strDescription, IMG_UNCHECKED, static_cast<LPARAM>(iNumRows) - 1L);
```

You don't really need the `L` (or `LL` for 64-bit builds) suffix, but it makes it clear to future readers that you know what you're doing. A more *precise* (but ugly) specification of the constant would be `static_cast<LPARAM>(1)`.

Comment: Is that `uL` shortcode for `unsigned long`? Is that basically what a `LPARAM` is then?

Comment: Shall we delete our obsolete comments now?